# React useState doesn't execute code after declaration

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, axios

I'm working on a React project and encountering a strange issue with the `useState` hook. Specifically, I have a custom hook named `useAxios` that uses `useState` to manage state. However, any `console.log` statements placed after the `useState` declarations don't seem to be executing, and I'm having trouble figuring out why.

```js
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import config from "../config";
import axios from "axios";

axios.defaults.baseURL = config.backendUrl;

export const useAxios = (axiosParams) => {
  const {  method, url, requestConfig = {} } = axiosParams;

  console.log("above useState");

  const [response, setResponse] = useState([]);
  const [error, setError] = useState("");
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

  console.log("below useState");

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("inside useEffect");
    const controller = new AbortController();

    const fetchData = async () => {
      console.log("inside fetchdata");
      try {
        const res = await axios[method.toLowerCase()](url, {
          ...requestConfig,
          signal: controller.signal,
        });
        console.log("res", res);
        setResponse(res.data);
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err.message);
        setError(err.message);
      } finally {
        setLoading("fullfilled");
      }
    };

    fetchData();

    // clean up function
    return () => controller.abort();
  }, []);

    return [response, error, loading];
};
```

In the code above, you can see that I have `console.log` statements before and after the `useState` declarations. The strange thing is that the log statement before `useState` executes correctly, but the one after it does not.

Here is where I used the `useAxios`:

```js
import { createSlice, createAsyncThunk } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import config from "../../../config";
import { useAxios } from "../../../CustomHook/useAxios";

const initialState = {
  products: [],
  loading: "idle",
  error: null,
};

export const fetchProducts = createAsyncThunk(
  "products/fetchProducts",
  async (queryParams) => {

    const [product, error, loading] = useAxios({
      method: "GET",
      url: `/get-product-list?${queryParams}`,
    });

    if (loading === "rejected") {
      throw error;
    }

    if (loading === "idle") {
      console.log("lodingggg");
    }

    if (loading === "fullfilled") {
      console.log("fullfied");
    }

    return product; 
  }
);

const productSlice = createSlice({
  name: "products",
  initialState,
  reducers: {},
  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder.addCase(fetchProducts.pending, (state) => {
      state.loading = "pending";
    });
    builder.addCase(fetchProducts.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
      state.loading = "fulfilled";
      state.products = action.payload;
    });
    builder.addCase(fetchProducts.rejected, (state, action) => {
      state.loading = "rejected";
      state.error = action.error.message;
    });
  },
});

export default productSlice.reducer;
```

I've checked my component code, and I am calling the `useAxios` hook correctly. Additionally, I'm not seeing any errors in the console.

I've tried the following to troubleshoot:

Checking the component code to ensure the hook is being used properly.
Inspecting the console for any error messages.
Adding more console.log statements before and after the useState declarations to narrow down the issue.
Despite these efforts, I can't seem to identify why the console.log statement after useState is not running.

Has anyone encountered a similar issue or have any suggestions on how to debug this problem?

Comment: please share where you used useAxios

Comment: @NizarZizoune I have shared the code.

Comment: Custom hooks should be used inside a React functional component

Comment: @NizarZizoune do you mean, when i am using useAxios, it should be inside a functional component?

Comment: Yes, think about it logically. Your function useAxios  does invoke useState witch can only be used inside a functional component. Move it over to your component

Comment: @NizarZizoune yea, you are right. Is there any way i can use a custom axios setup like this outside a functional component, like inside redux.

Comment: You can pass whatever variables from your ```component``` to your ```reducer``` via your ```actions``` as params

Answer (score 0):

How are you importing the hook? useState is used inside function components which need a default export. Also, you don't need to include your hook name in the export. Just save the hook file as "hooks/use-axios.js" and export the component with this:

export default () => {
...